# How to implement conditional upload file using multer?

Tags: express

I have 2 `input type="file"` on a single form and I want file from left input upload into "left" folder and right to "right"
but how could I know what file was uploaded from right or left input?

```
const express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();
const multer = require("multer");

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send(`
  <form action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <input type="file" name="left"/><br>
  <input type="file" name="right" /><br>
  <button  type="submit">send</button>
</form>
`);
});

app.post("/upload", function (req, res, fields) {
  const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
      if (true /*if from input name left*/) {
        
        cb(null, "left");
      } else {
        //if from input name right
        cb(null, "right");
      }
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
      cb(null, file.originalname);
    },
  });

  const upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
  }).fields([{ name: "left" }, { name: "right" }]);

  upload(req, res, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
  });
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using an upload with fields like this `const upload = multer({ storage: storage, }).fields([{ name: "left" }, { name: "right" }]);`

and it is supposed for the field names to be identical to form-data appended values,
so all you need to do is to access the request files correctly like following:

for the 'left' file input you access the uploaded file with:
req.files['left'][0]
and for the 'right' file input you also can access it the same way:
req.files['right'][0]
[[image: An example from multer npm1]